# Display logged in user name and lastname on page

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I want to display the first an lastname of my users on a welcome site.
I have some code in my functions.php that let me show the first name. How can I change the code to show both first and last?

This is my code for the shortcode:

```
function custom_shortcode_func() {
    ob_start();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'Willkommen ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('current_user', 'custom_shortcode_func');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do a `var_dump()` of `$current_user` to see what it contains. You'll see there is a similar property to `user_firstname`: `user_lastname`.

You'll probably want a space between the first and last name, so a small edit should add the last name:

```
function custom_shortcode_func() {
    ob_start();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'Willkommen ' . $current_user->user_firstname . ' ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('current_user', 'custom_shortcode_func');
```

As you can see you're already getting the last name and other data, so the tweak just adds a space character and the last name.

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you.

Comment: It's good practice to mark this answer accepted with the checkmark next to the 0, so others know it did the trick. :)